# Is there any way to get information about the latest automatic backup of my android app?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I've already implemented the autoBackup feature (I didn't implement a BackupAgent) in my Android app following the indications I've found in the Android Developers documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#define-device-conditions)

I've also tested the backup and restore following this page (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup) and it seems that is all working fine!

But now I would also like to show some information about the size or the date of the last backup made, in the settings of my app, so that I can inform the user (something similar to what you can see by going to the Whatsapp settings where it talks about the backup of the chats).

Example: [WhatsApp Backup information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHkkR.png)

Is there any way to get this kind of information? thanks

Comment: I guess if you implemented `BackupAgent`, you could save that information on your `SharedPreferences` on its `onBackup` hook. I don't think you could do this by only using auto backup

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've implemented a BackupAgent class and now all work as expected.